# Select highest season and episode (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of episodes that looks like this:

[image]

I want to take the highest `season` and then the highest `episode` from the highest season from `series` `1` for example (WHERE series = 1). The output wil be:

```
id | episode | season | series
8       3        1         1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: the highest season is 4, not 1 ?*

Comment: @Begueradj I want it from a spesific `series`, in the example I mentioned `1`

Comment: Coffee time guys... WHERE series = 1 ORDER BY season DESC, episode DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @Begueradj The highest `season` from the `series = 1`

Comment: As described, this problem does not fall within the greatest-n-per-group class of problems. There is no 'per group' here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE series = 1 ORDER BY season DESC, episode DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Another possibilty would be to "SELECT MAX(...)..." and use it in the WHERE-clause.

Comment: SELECT MAX() is not a possibility, except as a subquery of a larger and unnecessary solution

Comment: And that's why I gave you +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, MAX(episode) AS episode, MAX(season) AS season, series
FROM yourTable
WHERE series=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM testTable
WHERE series= 1  and (season in (select MAX(season) from testTable))
ORDER BY episode DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

“What is the highest item number?”